# How to get Session Class in latest Facebook Android SDK 4.6.0

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to use this class [**Session**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/class/Session/) in the code snippet below. When I click on `Check out the latest version` I get [this Page not found link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Session/). What is the replacement for `Session` here?

The `Session` variable cannot get resolved.

[image]

I have already checked that the facebook SDK has been imported because able to import `import com.facebook.FacebookSdk; //Facebook SDK` fine with no issues using Gradle:
`compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'`

Answer (score 1):

The `Session` class has been removed from the the SDK at the version 4.0 - at March 25, 2015. You can find information about this in the [change-log](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4.x)

> Replacement Classes - Session and UserSettingsFragment have been
>   removed and replaced by the LoginManager and AccessToken classes.
>   LoginActivity is replaced by FacebookActivity.

So now you should use `LoginManager` with the latest SDK versions.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to log out and flush the login cache. How to do that without the `Session` variable?

Comment: @user1406716, using `LoginManager` it can be achieved by calling `logOut()` [method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginManager/#class_methods)

Comment: Even if you are using LoginButton, for login workflow, you anyway can call `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();` to log out current user, clear it's token and cache.